# How to Find Coordinate Vector of a $ 2\times 2$ Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So i'm doing a question on a past midterm to study for my upcoming one, and i'm not quite sure what's going wrong here.
[Past midterm question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD8zB.png)

So I turned the basis in to these [vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBxFy.png) and then made an augmented matrix that i RREF'd it to this:
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&\upharpoonleft&2 \\ 0&1&0&0&\upharpoonleft&0 \\ 0&0&1&0&\upharpoonleft&1 \\ 0&0&0&1&\upharpoonleft&2  \end{bmatrix}

Therefore my Coordinate vector should be:
\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}

However it can't be because when i multiply it back with the ordered basis vectors, it does not equal the matrix A. Sorry about the links, i can't embed photos yet and am struggling with the TeX commands

Comment: Please have a read through the Help pages, in particular http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference